# setting div height 100% giving strange result?

Tags: css, html

I have got three child div (placed next to each otehr) in one parent dive. The first child div has some content in it and stretches as per its content length. The other two child div has no content in them, and I want them to have same height like the first child div.

After reading in articles on net, I set the height=100% of html, body, parent and second & third child div. Now when I check in browser, the height of html, body and child divs exceeding the height of first child div in normal view. And if I open the inspect element window, then height of html, body and child divs goes lesser than first child div. The margin of difference of height in both view is approx of 30%.

I'm using skeleton framework. Please help.

<------- code added below ------->

I added following lines in layout css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
 }

body {
   height: 100%;
 }

.main { <!--class name applied to container or parent div -->
   height: 100%;
 }

.first-child, .second-child, .third-child { <!--class name given two three divs from left to right-->
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Apart this, I added respective class names to respective divs in html.

Answer (score 0):

The **inspect element** panel decreases the size of the browser window. Since you are using a percentage of the window as the height, you are altering the 2nd and 3rd divs as well as the html, body, and parent; but not the first child div.

Comment: adding first child div 'height: 100%' doesn't make any difference. Problem still persists. You can replicate this issue by adding height attribute in default html / css package of skeleton as well.

Comment: To make my question more clear, I've uploaded an html package at following url: 2shared.com/file/bVpgHDUx/html.html Open the html file in browser to see the issue. See Keeping open and close inspect element panel and scrolling the page.

Comment: Just paste relevant code in your question or create a JS fiddle at jsfiddle.net. I'm not downloading your html file.

Comment: I've added code in original post. Well, I created the html/css pack link and asked to download the html/css pack as it could has the preview what I want to say. Its no spam, no x-number lines of coding, only skeleton framework base files and my lines of code as added now.

Comment: I'm not downloading the file but if you go here: http://jsfiddle.net/KAVgT/ you'll see what you should do to allow us to answer your question. Nobody is going to download a file from a new user when there is absolutely no reason to do so. JS Fiddle is too easy to use to justify asking us to download your file. And providing the code above is useless because (1) it would not result in divs that are 'side by side', and (2) css in this case is useless without the html.

Comment: fine, I've created a JS Fiddle with my HTML and CSS code. URL is: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CPK9q/6/)

However, its not reflecting the same output (in output panel) as it does in browser, though I've added all html/css there. Not sure if I created the fiddle as it must be, curse to my novice skills of using fiddle. I didn't use it initially for the same reason, but thanks to you I now learned something about it :).

Lastly few detail about code, I've only added css in layout.css. Rest two css code is default of skeleton framework. Thanks for all your support :)